# Debug timer start callback

Tags: matlab, timer

Consider the following function `test_timer`:

```
function test_timer
TestTimer = timer('Period', 1, 'TasksToExecute', Inf);

TestTimer.TimerFcn = @tfcn;
TestTimer.StartFcn = @sfcn;

start(TestTimer);

function sfcn(hObject, eventdata)
    disp('init');
    pause(1)
    disp('init done');


function tfcn(hObject, eventdata)
    disp('tfcn');
    stop(hObject);
```

First, run `test_timer` as is. The functions are called in the expected order, i.e. first all of `sfcn`, then `tfcn`. Now place a breakpoint in `sfcn`, e.g. on line 10 and run `test_timer`. `tfcn` will be called immediately.

This behaviour is annoying when trying to debug setting up data structures for later use by the timer. Is there any way to block queueing / execution of the timer callback when debugging another callback?

Comment: Have you tried the option `'BusyMode'` with value `'queue'`? I don't understand from the doc if it affects only timer functions or also the start function. If not, the only option I see is to call `sfcn` before starting the timer when you debug.

Comment: Or put a `StartDelay` of several seconds, taking into account the duration of lauching the timer, function and stopping at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB confirmed this is a bug. They have suggested a workaround, by wrapping the timer in an object:

`TimerWrapper.m`:

```
classdef TimerWrapper
properties
TimerObj
StartFcn = {};
end

methods

function obj = TimerWrapper(varargin)
obj.TimerObj = timer(varargin{:});
obj.StartFcn = obj.TimerObj.StartFcn;
obj.TimerObj.StartFcn = @(~,~){};
end

function start(obj)
if ~isempty(obj.StartFcn)
obj.StartFcn(obj.TimerObj,'start');
end
start(obj.TimerObj);
end

function stop(obj)
stop(obj.TimerObj);
end

end
end
```

and `test_timer_new.m`:

```
function test_timer_new
t = timer('Period', 1, 'TasksToExecute', Inf);

t.TimerFcn = @tfcn;
t.StartFcn = @sfcn;

TestTimer = TimerWrapper(t);

start(TestTimer)

function sfcn(hObject, eventdata)
    disp('init');
    pause(1)
    disp('init done');


function tfcn(hObject, eventdata)
    disp('tfcn');
    [actst] = rand > .6;
    if actst

        stop(hObject);
    end
```